# then() callback firing before promise is resolved in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Using node.js version 7.7.2, I'd like to execute an asynchronous function and then a different function once the first function has completed like this:

```js
function foo() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do some async stuff
    console.log('foo is about to resolve');
    resolve();
  });
}
    
function bar(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

foo().then(bar('bar has fired'));
```

The issue is that this setup prints 'bar has fired' followed by 'foo is about to resolve'.  What I expect is that bar will wait to fire until the promise returned by foo has resolved.  Am I misunderstanding how then() queues callbacks in the node.js event loop?

Thanks

Comment: because you are calling bar....and assigning what it returns to the then.

Comment: Have you tried it without calling bar explicitly (aka remove the `()`)?

Comment: Whenever you have `x(y())`, `y` is called *first* and its return value is passed to `x`. This has nothing to do with `.then`, promises or event loops. Arguments are *always* eagerly evaluated.

Comment: Gotcha.  What if I want to pass parameters into bar?  Does that make bar no longer immediately invoked? I'll update the question to reflect this since it more closely represents the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: `.then` expects a function, so in that case you pass a function that calls `bar` with the parameter: `.then(() => bar('bar has fired'))`

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in a comment, pass a function to `then` that, when called, will call `bar` with your params.

```js
function foo() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do some async stuff
    console.log('foo is about to resolve');
    resolve();
  });
}
    
function bar(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

foo().then(function(){bar('bar has fired')});
```