# Using async/await, array.length still shows as 0

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

My `async/await` function:

```
  async function search(pattern) {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/searchIndex.json");
    const index = res.data;
    const options = {
      keys: ["title", "content"],
      shouldSort: true,
      threshold: 0.5,
      maxPatternLength: 50
    };
    const fuse = new Fuse(index, options);
    return fuse.search(pattern);
  }
```

Where it's called, and then I push the object to an array `results` and then execute `renderAutoComplete`

```
function handleSearchInput(event) {
  input = event.target.value;
  if (input.length >= 3) {
    results =[];
    showAutoComplete = true;
    search(input).then( val => results.push(...val)).then(renderAutoComplete());
  }
}
```

But, in `renderAutoComplete` `results` always equals `0` and I can't access the data. So this means I have an issue somewhere in my `async/await`.
Of course, if I `console.log` I get:
[image: array console log]

Comment: you are calling `renderAutoComplete` _before_ the promise resolves.

Comment: `search(input).then( val => results.push(...val)).then(renderAutoComplete())` -> `search(input).then(renderAutoComplete)`. There's really no need to even declare `results`, just let your `val` array be passed implicitly as a parameter to `renderAutoComplete`

Comment: Instead of passing the return value of `renderAutoComplete()` to `then()`, pass the function reference --> `then(renderAutoComplete)`

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644230/then-callback-firing-before-promise-is-resolved-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include brackets in your code, because in that manner `renderAutoComplete` function will be called before resolving the promise. You should put just a function and let `Promise` mechanism call it when it's finished.

`search(input).then( val => results.push(...val)).then(renderAutoComplete);`

Also I would recommend to change `renderAutoComplete` function to accept `results` as an argument instead of using a global variable.

```
function renderAutoComplete (results) {
...
}
...
search(input).then(renderAutoComplete);
```